# iPhone password problem

Tags: iphone, ios, password, screen-lock

I have a really weird problem. My girlfriend recently changed her iPhone  password. The problem is that the iPhone says that the password is incorrect, but she had to repeat the code twice when she changed it and I do not think that she could have made it wrong twice.

Another weird thing is that it accepted  the password few times but now it keeps locking for "5" , "10" , "15" etc minutes (right now we are on 15 minutes) and event finger did not work very well since she installed iOS 10. Is is possible that there is some error or something like that?
Note: She has 64GB iPhone 6

Thank you very much.. :D

Comment: Sounds like she forgot her password, or there's some really bad bug.

Comment: I guess so, but It is supposed to be her phone number which I do not think she would forget, but...

Comment: If you don't think she has forgotten her passcode, talk to Apple right away. Go to https://getsupport.apple.com